# Unable to pass 2-Dimensional array while using recursion in c++

Tags: c++, recursion, multidimensional-array, pass-by-reference, call-by-value

I saw an answer in **stackoverflow** regarding how to pass a `2d-array` in a function there are 3 or more methods given when I tried one of them it worked just fine. But when I'm trying to use that method in backtracking it is giving me an error.

I tried declaring it globally but I want to learn how to use it this way

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int callAgain(int,int);
int call(int,int);

int call(int arr[][5],int n)
{
  if(n==1)
    return 0;

  cout<<"anything";

  callAgain(arr,n-1);     //getting error here.

  return 0;
 }
int callAgain(int arr[][5],int n)
{
  call(arr,n);
  return 0;
 }
int main(){

int arr[5][5];
memset(arr,0,sizeof(arr));
call(arr,5);

return 0;
}
```

error: invalid conversion from int(*)[5] to int [-fpremissive]

Comment: There are a lot of issues with the code you're showing (starts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)). The basic culprit is to use _raw c-style arrays_ with c++ code. You should rather learn how to facilitate `std::array` and `std::vector` correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Your forward declarations for `call` and `callAgain` promise that the first argument will be an `int`, but then when you implement them you say the first argument is a 2D array.

Compilers don't appreciate being lied to...

Comment: Not necessary a lie, might be implemented in another TU :)

Comment: @Jarod42: There is exactly *one blank line* between the forward declaration of `call` & its implementation.  (And what is a TU?)

Comment: Well, [Translation Unit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106149/what-is-a-translation-unit-in-c), I guess.

Comment: When I'm calling the call function in my main function and passing an array then also it should have given me an error because like you said the call is also declared with int.

Comment: How many times/ways do you want it to tell you this is wrong?